# Error while compiling qt-dab with Qt (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I am trying to compile qt-dab by using the command line:

```
qmake qt-dab.pro
make
```

But I get these error messages:

```
/usr/bin/ld : ne peut trouver -lqwt-qt5
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [linux-bin/qt-dab-0.998] Erreur 1
```

"qmake -v" gives me `QMake version 3.0` using Qt version 5.2.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu.

Moreover, I installed the qwt-6.1.3 library. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

The linker can not find the library: `qwt-qt5`.

If you've installed the qwt library, you will want to find where it is located.
It sounds like you may have installed version 6 of the library,
but are trying to link with version 5 (which may be non-existent on your machine).

When you find the correct library on your system, you can tell the linker which to directories to search for it using the `-L` flag.

Comment: Do you mean I should add -L and the path to the version 5 of Qt in the command line?

Comment: Yes.  `-L path/to/lib`